# Installing Temporal Tables extension (contrib extension) on windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation, postgresql-extensions

I am trying to install this [Temporal Tables](http://clarkdave.net/2015/02/historical-records-with-postgresql-and-temporal-tables-and-sql-2011/) extension into my localhost installation of PostgreSQL. (pg9.4, windows 7)

I have figured out I needed to put the files into the 9.4/share/contrib folder (currently the files are at 9.4/share/contrib/temporal_tables-1.0.2) but I cannot figure out how to make CREATE EXTENSION work. I know I have to do the windows equivalent of "make install", and I would like to avoid needing to use Visual Studio if I can.

Comment: Please give us more info.  You can not run "CREATE EXTENSION temporal_tables;"  or else ?

Comment: my issue is I was working in windows; I've started up a linux VM now so that ought to solve my problems with working in windows

Answer (score 1):

## From [the docs](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables),

### Compiling Yourself

If you are running Windows, you need to run the MSBuild command in the Visual Studio command prompt.

```
msbuild /p:pgversion=9.4 /p:configuration=Release /p:platform=x64
```

The platforms available are x64 and x86 and the configuration are 9.2, 9.3 , 9.4, and 9.5.

### Compiled Download

Or you can download the [latest released zip here.](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables/releases/latest)

### Installing

Then you must copy the DLL from the project into the PostgreSQL's lib directory and the .sql and .control files into the directory share\extension.

```
copy x64\9.4\temporal_tables.dll "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib"
copy *.control "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\share\extension"
copy *.sql "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\share\extension"
```

Once the extension is installed, you can add it to a database. Connect to a database as a super user and do this:

```
$ CREATE EXTENSION temporal_tables;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, you also have to copy [the compiled DLLs](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables/releases) to your PostgreSQL `lib` directory. [Step-by-step instructions](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables#installation) are in the manual.